# How to find an array which is having atleast 3 values greater than 4 in php

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

**$arr = array(4, 2, 3, 4, 5);**

How to find the array is containing atleast 3 values which are greater than or equal to 4?

I just want to maintain a flag that the array holds 3 values equal to or greater than 4.

Comment: 4 is coming twice. Will it be considered as one count or two counts ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya It will be counting two times Sir..

Answer (score 2):

Using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$total = array_reduce($arr, function($num, $val) {
  if ($val >= 4) $num++;
  return $num;
}, 0);
```

Comment: Can be a really bad idea if the array is big.... Suppose that the first three value fit the requirement, this method will however loop until the end of the array...

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the array, set the value to a counter.

```
$counter = 0;
$hasMoreThan3 = false;
foreach($array as $element) {
    if($element > 3) {
        $counter++;
        if($counter >= 3) {
            $hasMoreThan3 = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($hasMoreThan3);
```

If the array is short, you can filter

```
count(array_filter($array, function($e) {
    return $e > 3;
}));
```

Comment: You mean `if ($element > 4)` as mentioned in the question?

Comment: "equal or greater than 4" is the same as > 3

Comment: Yes, for integers, But not for floating numbers.

Comment: Don't nest break condition. Not this way or the loop will continue in some cases until the end of the array...

Comment: No, the break doesn't affect the `if`, as you can see here: https://3v4l.org/hDJSn

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this :

```
$arr = array(4, 2, 3, 4, 5);
var_dump(threeValuesOver($arr, 3));
function threeValuesOver($array,$value){
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($array as $entry){
        if($entry > $value) $counter++;
        if($counter >= 3) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is fast simple code:

```
$arr = array(4, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$countval = 0;
foreach($arr as $val) {
    $countval+=($val >=4)?1:0;
}
$flag = ($countval>2);
```

It will count values equal or greater 4 and if it counts 3 or more it will echo.

Try this another code:

```
$arr = array(4, 2, 3, 4, 5);
//--- 1
$arrdif = array(0, 1, 2, 3);
$flag = (count(array_diff($arr, $arrdif))==3);
//--- 2
rsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
$flag = (array_search(3, $arr)==3);
```

Comment: Your code will loop until the end of the array and it is a bad idea in some cases...

Comment: It will reach end of array in case if values equal or greater 4 counts less than 3. If you would like to count all array elements it should be loop until end of array.

Answer (score -1):

This is the simple solution after optimizing 'msg' solution

```
$bool = array_reduce($arr, function($num, $val) {
  if ($val >= 4) $num++;
   return $num;
}, 0) >= 3;
```